# Oracle 11g Database Creation

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle11g

I am a newbie in Oracle databases and compared with my experiences with SQL Server and MySQL, Oracle is not as easy. Question is, when I tried to create a database using DB Configuration Assistant, when I look at the database using SQL Developer, there are already tables on it. Why does it have something like system tables on it if its a custom database. How can I instead put my own tables on that database.

Comment: Are you *sure* you need a new database? Usually a database in MySQL and SQL Server maps to a user in Oracle. A "database" in Oracle is (more or less) the *whole installation*. It is something completely different than a "database" in SQL Server or MySQL

Comment: im not sure to be honest. what i do want is to have a db in oracle the same as i have a db in mysql/sql server where i can create table, views, enter data, etc.

Comment: If you already have a running Oracle instance, you also have a database. Just create a user and create the tables after connecting with that user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shoud begin connecting as sys and creating a user(and implicitly, a schema). In that schema you can put your tables.

[see docs to create user](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_8003.htm)

Comment: I see. Ill get back to see after I create another user for that DB.

Comment: can you advise me what role should i grant a user to be able to create a database and do CRUD on it.

Comment: you have an Oracle database installed and I think is up. If you created the user and conected with that user you can't create tables(I don't know the default behavior - but I believe this won't happen), you may run an `grant create table to your_username`;

Comment: thanks. I have got in to that part. problem is, when I create a table using 'system' user and grant it to 'my_user'... the table doesnt seem to show up on my_user's connection.

Comment: First, you should not create a table with user system or in tablespace SYSTEM. Second, If you grant `select on your_sys_table to your_user`, you'll be able to read from it. For insert you should grant insert.

Answer (score 2):

Please read the Oracle documentation.  It is comprehensive, online and free.  I understand the size of it may be dauting compared to the relative pamphlet which constitutes the docs for MSSQL :) but as you will find out Oracle does a lot more.

To get you started there is a 2-Day DBA Guide.  [Find it here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14196/toc.htm).  This has chapters on [creating the database](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14196/install.htm#CHDGJGHB) (which maybe you should have read already) and [administering users](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14196/users_secure.htm#CHDJBHHI), which will address your immediate concerns.